# We should remove the [recommendations] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The first off-topic close reason is

> Questions asking for game recommendations are off-topic.

but we still have the [recommendations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag. I know that the tag description says that these kind of questions are "generally deprecated" on the site, but as we all know, users don't read. Plus, "generally deprecated" doesn't mean "completely off-topic". The existence of this tag encourages people to ask these questions.

In addition, it is a meta tag, which we should avoid. It describes the question itself, not the quality of the question.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this tag should go away.  Most of the questions thus tagged are closed, which is a hint.

Before we nuke it, though, we need to make sure that the affected questions will still end up with appropriate tags.  About half of these questions have a singleton [recommendations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) tag, meaning they'll be untagged after removing this one.  Four of those questions are still open.  It's not entirely obvious to me how some of these should be tagged.

Maybe we don't care if closed questions are untagged, but we should decide that rather than just letting it happen.

The singletons:

- [Best strategic games and play online](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/9553/best-strategic-games-and-play-online)
- [Which games qualify as Gateway Games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/7606/which-games-qualify-as-gateway-games)
- [What interesting 3-player strategy games are available?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6948/what-interesting-3-player-strategy-games-are-available)
- [What is a good resource to discover new games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/6185/what-is-a-good-resource-to-discover-new-games) (NOT CLOSED)
- [How can I arrange a Christmas gift exchange for board game geeks?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5703/how-can-i-arrange-a-christmas-gift-exchange-for-board-game-geeks) (NOT CLOSED)
- [Are there any magazines similar to InQuest Gamer in print today?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5341/are-there-any-magazines-similar-to-inquest-gamer-in-print-today) (NOT CLOSED)
- [One vs Many board games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4465/one-vs-many-board-games)
- [Card Games for Three Players?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/card-games-for-three-players)
- [What is a good board game to use for a programming competition](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4205/what-is-a-good-board-game-to-use-for-a-programming-competition)
- [Advice for an experienced gamer who'd like to play nomic games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3281/advice-for-an-experienced-gamer-whod-like-to-play-nomic-games)
- [Eurogames suitable for playing outside](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2928/eurogames-suitable-for-playing-outside)
- [What are great gamer games that are still great for uncompetitive groups.](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2855/what-are-great-gamer-games-that-are-still-great-for-uncompetitive-groups)
- [What are some great 2-player games for a couple to play?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2412/what-are-some-great-2-player-games-for-a-couple-to-play)
- [Quick engaging card games that can be learned quickly by a new group](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2333/quick-engaging-card-games-that-can-be-learned-quickly-by-a-new-group)
- [Good travel games for two players, especially for playing on trains?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2211/good-travel-games-for-two-players-especially-for-playing-on-trains)
- [Best Light Strategy Party Games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/2050/best-light-strategy-party-games)
- [What are some good 8 player games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1988/what-are-some-good-8-player-games)
- [Games that can be played with just normal playing cards that are engrossing enough for a hardcore gamer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/games-that-can-be-played-with-just-normal-playing-cards-that-are-engrossing-enou)
- [What are good games to play during a one-hour lunch break?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/what-are-good-games-to-play-during-a-one-hour-lunch-break)
- [Games that are quick to teach to new people, yet still fun and strategical](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1350/games-that-are-quick-to-teach-to-new-people-yet-still-fun-and-strategical)
- [What games are suitable for a large number of people with only a pack of playing cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1107/what-games-are-suitable-for-a-large-number-of-people-with-only-a-pack-of-playing)
- [Where can I find reviews of board games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/762/where-can-i-find-reviews-of-board-games)  (NOT CLOSED)
- [Hero Quest type games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/711/hero-quest-type-games)
- [Good games for playing in a bar](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/529/good-games-for-playing-in-a-bar)
- [Games that play well with a wide range of different numbers of players](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/348/games-that-play-well-with-a-wide-range-of-different-numbers-of-players)
- [Good board games for single player](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/4/good-board-games-for-single-player)
- [Board games for two players](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/212/board-games-for-two-players)

Comment: I suggest that we start by deleting the closed questions in this list that are clearly off-topic.

Comment: Well, we should review them first to see if there's anything worth keeping/merging/historical-locking.  Sometimes a bad question attracts good answers.  I haven't looked at these; I only compiled the list.