# Can we get rid of the recommendations tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, closed-questions

We've previously decided to [ban recommendation questions](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/656/should-we-ban-game-recommendation-questions-done) and then [really banned them](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/663/game-recommendation-questions-are-banned) and then [decided again to remove the tag](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/we-should-remove-the-recommendations-tag), but [recommendations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) is still there!

To finish the job, perhaps we could:

- <s>**close the last two questions**</s>: [How can I arrange a Christmas gift exchange for board game geeks?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/5703/how-can-i-arrange-a-christmas-gift-exchange-for-board-game-geeks) and [Where can I find a list of cooperative “beat the game” games?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/13636/where-can-i-find-a-list-of-cooperative-beat-the-game-games)
- **link the game recommendations close reason** to this [new canonical meta question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/409) (content is from the tag wiki, cleaned up slightly), instead of the [one it currently points to](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/970/409) which is more historical
- (optional) **add links to the other resources to the close reason** as well, along the lines of "Try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49/board-and-card-games), [BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/), or your local game store. For details on why, and more resources, see [this meta question](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1307/409)."
- **burninate the tag** (yay?)

Does that make sense?

(This question is distinct from even the past decision to remove the tag it's a new *request* for certain concrete actions, not all of which were mentioned previously.)

Comment: This is a duplicate of [We should remove the \[recommendations\] tag](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/we-should-remove-the-recommendations-tag). The actionable items described here belong in an *answer* to the older question.

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. This is a new question, making new requests for action (some of which can only be done by moderators).

Comment: And.. normally downvotes here would indicate disagreement with the ideas in the post, i.e. this plan - I know the downvoter may not be reading, but it'd be helpful to know what you don't like about it!

Comment: All right, there are no longer any open questions with the tag - it should be safe to remove. Mods - unfortunately I think it's impossible to edit close reasons, so if you agree about changing the link(s), you'd have to add a new one and deactivate the old one to do this.

Comment: We should probably also blacklist the tag.

Comment: Made the burnination request explicit, sorry I neglected to do that. We got a couple more recommendation questions (one of them tagged as such) recently, so I do think this is worth doing. Changing the close reason would be lovely (mods?), but getting rid of the tag is still good.

Answer (score 1):

1. Looks like the community has handled these two.
2. We've modified the close reason to point to the canonical meta question.
3. I think the links in the canonical question are sufficient - cluttering the message doesn't seem like a great idea.
4. I don't think a grand total of three votes between the Q and A in [We should remove the recommendations tag](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1120/we-should-remove-the-recommendations-tag) justifies the statement "*decided again to remove the ([recommendations](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/recommendations)) tag*". Monica's point there about becoming [untagged](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) is valid. In my opinion, removing the tag needs further discussion. Is there anything on the SE meta about this?

Comment: The only questions that'll become untagged are closed questions. One more crept in since I posted this, but it was a bad usage of the tag (not about game recommendations, *and* was used as a meta tag) so I just removed it. I don't think I saw any other discussion about it, but I figured that the fact that the tag is explicitly described in its wiki as being for game recommendation questions (which are off topic) is a good reason not to expect it to ever make sense on any open questions. Not a huge deal though.